# Dependencies are null with the German Parser from Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I tried to parse german sentences with the Stanford CoreNLP and the german models Version 3.6.
On the website it says that Dependency Parsing is supported for german but when I parse a sentence the dependencies are always null.

I use the scala script within deepdive to run the NLP with the following properties:

```
val germanProps = new Properties()
germanProps.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, ner, parse")
germanProps.put("tokenize.language", "de")
germanProps.put("pos.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger")
germanProps.put("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz")
germanProps.put("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "false")
germanProps.put("ner.useSUTime", "false")
germanProps.put("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz")
```

Is there a problem with my configuration or why does the german parser not work?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the NN dependency parser to get German dependency parses.

The info is here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml

Also you'll need the German models jar available here:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

So basically the StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties should look like
  "annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, ner, deparse" and "depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz"
to avoid confusion?

Because on the website it says that the parse-annotation "Provides full syntactic analysis, using both the constituent and the dependency representations. "
That's why I thought I could get the dependencies with it.

Comment: Yes those should be the correct settings.  Basically no one has ever implemented converting the German constituency parses to dependency parses (which is implemented for English for instance), but recently we built some NN models for the pure dependency parser for German.