# Stanford-NLP German dependency parsing not working properly

Tags: stanford-nlp

I recently discovered (reading the question below) that I could obtain german dependencies with the Stanford parser, using the NNDependencyParser.

[Dependencies are null with the German Parser from Stanford CoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175963/dependencies-are-null-with-the-german-parser-from-stanford-corenlp)

My problem is, my parsed dependencies are always simply adjacent words in the sentence, no real tree structure. Parsing "Die Sonne scheint am Himmel." would get me pairs of ("Die", "Sonne"), ("Sonne", "scheint"), ("scheint", "am") etc. as dependencies even when using collaped dependencies.

```
    String modelPath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_German.gz";
    String taggerPath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/german/german-hgc.tagger";
    String text = "Ich sehe den Mann mit dem Fernglas.";

    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(taggerPath);
    DependencyParser parser = DependencyParser.loadFromModelFile(modelPath);

    DocumentPreprocessor tokenizer = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(text));
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : tokenizer) {
      List<TaggedWord> tagged = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);

      GrammaticalStructure gs = parser.predict(tagged);

      for (TypedDependency td : gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed()) {
         System.out.println(td.toString());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, our German dependency parsing model is currently broken (somehow the French model was included in the release and we currently don't seem to have a working German model).

However, you could train your own model using the data from the [Universal Dependencies project](http://www.universaldependencies.org). You can find some information on how to train the parser on its [project page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml).